# ORACLE SQL, Select non-matching fields from same table in a row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-query-store

I have following table in Oracle:

```
Id    Acct    Name
==================
1     123     Anyone
1     234     Anyone
2     435     Someone
2     675     Someone
2     732     Someone
3     765     Anonymous
4     987     Hidden
4     987     Hidden
```

and I need the following output:

```
Id    Acct1   Acct2   Name
==========================
1     123     234     Anyone
2     435     675     Someone
2     435     732     Someone
```

So, I only need to show the records with non-matching Acct#, but both the account numbers in one line as above.
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.acct, t2.acct
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.name = t2.name and t1.acct <> t2.acct;
```

Or, if you can have more than two accounts, then perhaps `listagg()` is more appropriate:

```
select t.id, t.name, listagg(acct, ',') within group (order by acct)
from t
group by t.id, t.name
having min(acct) <> max(acct);
```